# How to read csv file in dataframe with different delimiter in header as ''," and rest of the rows are separated with "|"

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Have csv file header was comma separated and rest of the rows are seperated with another delimiter "|" .How to handle this different delimiters scenario ? Please advise .

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
var df1: DataFrame = null
df1=spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").option("inferSchema", "false")
          .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true") .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
.csv("/testing.csv")
df1.show(10)
```

this commands displays the headers are delimited seperately .But all the data was displayed in first column ,remaining columns are displayed with null values

Comment: you can try setting **spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "|")**

Answer (score 0):

Read the csv first and split the columns, create new dataframe.

```
df.show

+---------+----+-----+
|       Id|Date|Value|
+---------+----+-----+
|1|2020|30|null| null|
|1|2020|40|null| null|
|2|2020|50|null| null|
|2|2020|40|null| null|
+---------+----+-----+

val cols = df.columns
val index = 0 to cols.size - 1
val expr = index.map(i => col("array")(i))

df.withColumn("array", split($"Id", "\\|"))
  .select(expr: _*).toDF(cols: _*).show

+---+----+-----+
| Id|Date|Value|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|2020|   30|
|  1|2020|   40|
|  2|2020|   50|
|  2|2020|   40|
+---+----+-----+
```